# async, await, context and next does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.2

I just created a new empty web application using Core 2.2 and wanted to add a piece of middleware but I am not allowed to do so.

```
app.Use(async (context, next)) =>
        {
            await next;
        }
```

but it doesn't recognize either async, context, next or await. I've tried to search online but haven't come across anything with this trivial problem. Anyone knows what's causing it? I am using community 2019

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        await next();
    })
```

`app.Use()` accepts a function as parameter but you pass only `async (context, next)` as parameter.